# know the files in a folder on web server

Tags: java, webserver

With the java language I have no problem knowing the files contained in a local directory.
I can also download a certain file, on a web server on the internet, if I know the name but have not found any way to know the files contained in a folder on a web server.
Let me know if you think there is a way with java to do this or if this idea is not really feasible.
thank you.

Comment: [WebDAV](http://www.webdav.org/) (if the server supports it).

Comment: You normally can't, which is by design. Yes to above ^^ (WebDAV) but you might be lucky if the web server is configued to allow directory listing, in which case it will give you an html-formatted directory listing (rare)

Comment: @g00se There are any number of ways it might be configured to allow it: ssh, ftp, s3, etc. I was merely listing the one that exists explicitly for the purpose.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes I'm aware of that. I was agreeing with you